# How to force change layouts in Android

Tags: android

I have my app's orientation forced via

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

but when I want to change layout to landscape one (when device is rotated - i get the info via OrientationEventListener) it just doesnt render it as landscape. Is there any way how to force it? Just like imagine holding your device in portait mode but the layout is landscape. but not achieved via

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape" in manifest
```

I want to have it forced to portait because I'm building a camera app and it messes up the camera everytime and I want to have it like the default camera has it - no change, just the button orientation. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of camera apps achieve this by rotating `View`s and it's a good way to do it because you don't have to deal with Activity lifecycle **as well** as camera lifecycle. They have a locked orientation but they use accelerometer to get device rotation and then rotate `View`s accordingly.

Camera API gives you ability to [set camera rotation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) as well as picture orientation. Picture orientation should be set to zero because Camera API is unreliable with this.

Use accelerometer to determine real device rotation and set EXIF rotation of the picture to a correct one.

Comment: ok thanks for advice, i guess i'll do it that way, seems more simple. But Im still curious if there's a way to do it, it should be doable.

Comment: Handling orientation changes is more problematic than rotating some views, I think